# Update 2 tables with trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables:

- Table `Order`: IDOrder (PK), ProductId, Quantity, Price
- Table `Product`: ProductId (PK), Name,...., Quantity

I want to change quantity of product table when quantity of order table was **added**. But this does not work.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_updatequantity]
On [dbo].[order]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(quantity)
       UPDATE product 
       SET product.quantity = product.quantity - (inserted.quantity - deleted.quantity)
       FROM (deleted 
       INNER JOIN inserted ON deleted.IDOrder = inserted.IDOrder) 
       INNER JOIN product ON product.productId = inserted.ProductId
```

Comment: you should be aware that when more than one record is updated in table order this trigger will only gets fired once, and deleted and inserted will contain more than one record.

Comment: What should i do ? :(

Comment: What should you do ? You have some options, one is to write your update trigger as in the answer of Alfaiz, or you could do it the slow method, that is writing a cursor on the inserted table in your trigger. Than you can loop thru this cursor. Mind you this is very very bad for performance

Comment: Sorry, but i just learned SQL 1 month... I don't understand about cursor.

Comment: Maybe i should learn more. thank you

Comment: We all had to learn, but your on the right track on using a trigger for what you want. At least if I understand what you want correct

Comment: @GuidoG a cursor is NOT a good approach here. This can be done as a set based update not row by agonizing row.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, I mentioned in my comment that is very very bad. I just gave him some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
Create trigger [dbo].[trg_updatequantity]
On [dbo].[order]
FOR INSERT
AS

update product SET quantity= a.quantity - b.quantity
from product a 
inner join (
    SELECT  ProductID, SUM( ISNULL( quantity, 0))quantity 
    FROM    inserted 
    GROUP BY ProductID) b 
ON  a.ProductID = b.ProductID
```

Comment: Thnk you , i will try

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem, but i think quantity = a.quantity - b.quantity =)) Thank you

Comment: IF Product A Has 250 And you sell Some part product A Let Say 20 Then It will reduce The total Qty from Product which will Left 230 If I'm Not Wrong.But If quantity = a.quantity - b.quantity in This Case it will be ADDED right.so it will make tot_qty 270.if m not wrong

Comment: But when i use trigger, i choose 2 products, it only add 1

Comment: Is it possible if i use FOR EACH ROW?

Comment: are you Sure see this Query will you all inserted row with tot_qty product WIse  SELECT  ProductID, SUM( ISNULL( quantity, 0))quantity 
    FROM    inserted 
    GROUP BY ProductID

Comment: Are you Inserting Data Of 2 Different Product Or Single Product With Multiple Qty part.

Comment: i am inserting 2 diffirent products

Comment: SQL Server does **not** support the `FOR EACH ROW` approach - a trigger is **always** for **all rows** that were affected by an operation

Comment: @marc_s but when i insert 2 diffirent products, in visual studio still add 2 but in sql only 1.

Comment: This answer if for when you insert orders, you still need a trigger for when you update an order. Or maybe the client does not allow changing orders ?

Comment: i want when i insert orders, the quantity will decrease based on the product ordered .

Comment: Than this answer seems good to me. What is still the problem ?

Comment: i have tried to debug my web in visual, it work normaly, but in sql, only 1 record inserted. (i am using trigger of Alfaiz)

Comment: I dont understand your comment. The trigger of Alfaiz does not inserts anything, the inserts should come from your client which can be winforms, web, wpf,... If you are missing an insert that might not have to do with the trigger but with code in your client

Comment: Yes, for insert i use foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC. This work normaly but can't insert 2 products to order table. Because trigger? or not?

Comment: I dont think this is because of the trigger. Update your question and show us the table design of the order table, and your code that wants to insert 2 products

Comment: And also describe this problem, the problem that you cannot insert 2 products to one order

Comment: Oops, i know the reason in my code... not in sql. sorry everybody. And thank you